# Unable to locate ROS packages

Tags: ubuntu, github, ros, gazebo-simu

I am having trouble installing ROS packages through this tutorial https://nxp.gitbook.io/nxp-aim/installation-of-nxp-gazebo

```
$ ./foxy_install_aim.sh
```

is giving the following errors

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease      
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease    
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]     
Hit:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease                     
Fetched 110 kB in 2s (52.0 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'xorg' instead of 'x-window-system'
E: Unable to locate package gazebo11
E: Unable to locate package libgazebo11-dev
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-ros-base
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-desktop
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-cv-bridge
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-image-tools
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-image-transport
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-image-transport-plugins
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-image-pipeline
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-camera-calibration-parsers
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-camera-info-manager
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-launch-testing-ament-cmake
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-cv-bridge
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-vision-opencv
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-gazebo-dev
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-gazebo-msgs
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-gazebo-msgs-dbgsym
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-gazebo-plugins
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-gazebo-plugins-dbgsym
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-gazebo-ros
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-gazebo-ros2-control
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-gazebo-ros2-control-dbgsym
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-gazebo-ros2-control-demos
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-gazebo-ros2-control-demos-dbgsym
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-gazebo-ros-dbgsym
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-gazebo-ros-pkgs
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-vision-msgs
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-vision-msgs-dbgsym
sudo: geographiclib-get-geoids: command not found
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
./foxy_install_aim.sh: line 41: /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

The parts with "E:" seem like errors but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to fix these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone getting this error now, ROS-FOXY-* is outdated. ROS-IRON-* is working as I write this. Took me too long time to figure this out...
https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you are missing some sources in your apt configuration.

> From ros official documentation - https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html

**Setup Sources**

You will need to add the ROS 2 apt repositories to your system.
First, make sure that the Ubuntu Universe repository is enabled by
checking the output of this command.

```
apt-cache policy | grep universe
```

This should output a line like the one below:

```
500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
    release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
```

If you don’t see an output line like the one above, then enable the Universe repository with these instructions:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Now add the ROS 2 apt repository to your system.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl gnupg2 lsb-release
sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key  -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Then add the repository to your sources list.

```
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(source /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null
```

Update your apt repository caches after setting up the repositories.

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: I've tried this to the dot. When I try to install the ROS system (sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop) it keeps giving the same error: *E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-desktop*

Comment: @itsols just to share my experience. I had the same problem as you with rasp pi 3+ . Double and triple checked the ubuntu version - 22.04 jammy, but still nothing. Then I decided to do it all over again. And it worked! so "have you tried turning it on and off again"?

Comment: I am not sure how but I do recall switching Wi-Fi connections during the download. I guess a file got corrupt. And yes, after a reinstall, it did work.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of ubuntu are you using? I had the same issue with 22.04 which was not supported. I installed 20.04 and then it worked.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer to me. One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32950770)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem trying to setup ros2 humble on a Raspberry Pi and found the solution: The issue was my clock wasn't synchronized and the OS thought it was yesterday. I had to go into the settings and do two things: Under "Date & Time", manually set the date and time. Then, under "Privacy", turn Location Services on. THEN follow the steps in the ros documentation (https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html) and it worked. So I think maybe something about the curl command doesn't work if your clock is behind.