# Unable to locate package ros-iron-robotis-manipulator

Tags: ubuntu, package, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ros

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and ROS IRON
I am trying to :
sudo apt-get install ros-iron-robotis-manipulator
but it shows this
Unable to locate package ros-iron-robotis-manipulator

I even followed this :
[Unable to locate ROS packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72591758/unable-to-locate-ros-packages)
but no change

Answer (score 0):

[robotis-manipulator](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/robotis_manipulator/tree/master) package is not supported on latest versions of ROS2 so it's not built and not available in apt.

I see there is [ros2 branch](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/robotis_manipulator/tree/ros2). You could try building it from source. Basically download package from Github `ros2` branch (or other ros2 compatible branch). Put it in your workspace and build it like any other of your packages. You might need to fix compatibility issues or it might work first time

---